# Can be a particular visa required for recording a song?

Tags: music

Let's pretend i'm a indie musician and want to collaborate with another foreign indie musician and record a song featuring him/her.

I perfectly understand that actually touring/performing in public, and getting paid for it, would be considered as work, and, for example, a tourist/business visa/travel authorization, either for the musician to come into my country or for me to come into the musician's country, would be surely unfit for that purpose.

But what about just recording a song and then never performing it live at all in that country? Would that account as some kind of performance too and require getting petitioned for a work/specialty visa beforehands, even though i'm not getting paid at all for recording the song per se and even though i'm immediately leaving that country/the foreign musician is immediately leaving my country right after being done with the "meeting"?

I'm not referring to any country in particular. I just want to understand immigration laws better.

However, being immigration laws peculiar in some aspects to each country, a purely illustrative example, so that i can then study the immigration laws of each country myself, is needed, and this example is: a Russian-based musician that wants to collaborate with an UK-based musician.

Comment: Problem is, laws are made by countries, and are specific to those countries.  So answering this without "*referring to any country in particular*" is likely either impossible or overbroad (there being over 190 countries' laws to take into account).

Comment: @MadHatter Personally, i always seemed to notice some commonalities between different country's work-immigration related laws, but i get your point. I'm editing the question right now. Thanks.

Comment: The UK may not be the best generic example, given that a lot of their short term visas have now been rolled up into a single "Standard Visitor Visa" https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa including the former entertainer visitor visa, which nearly, but not quite fit your conditions https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entertainer-visitor-vat18/entertainer-visitor-vat18

Comment: @origimbo Why do you think it won't fit the conditions? I don't think that royalties from a song are the same thing as a salary, but i might be wrong, rather, i see this as a specific engagement.

Comment: So is non-paid volunteering with free lunch in some places is seen as payment if I recall correctly.

Comment: From the perspective of immigration law in many countries how much you are or are NOT getting paid for an activity does not make much, if any difference in if that activity is permissible on a tourist visa or not.  Making music together is a hobby but recording musician is also a regular job for paid professionals. The first is usually allowed, the later is (often? sometimes?) not permissible without a suitable visa/work permit.  Especially when you are not getting paid or only get expenses covered you may be considered unfair competition to the local workers who can't afford to work for free

Comment: @HBruijn True as long as the song is then sold and distributed in that country, but if the artist is paying a foreign recording facility for the song to be recorded and then it gets sold and distributed in another country (such as in Russia only, in our example) i fail to understand how the country's labour market gets affected... also, recording a single song of a particular album along with a foreign indie artist (sought after for its voice/talent) is a entirely different thing compared to recording a slew of albums in a particular country...

Comment: @ AI_  Based on text like https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/450237/Entering_the_UK_Arts_Ents_leaflet_August_2015.pdf  which has a fairly restrictive set of tick boxes to enter as a visitor, none of which are to record music commercially, and which specifically states "no paid or unpaid employment is permitted, apart from individuals taking part in a Permit Free Festival."

Comment: @origimbo Fine with that. Now i perfectly understand why music is getting number and more boring as years pass by. Unfortunately, talent is a very subjective thing.